# Water Droplet Render issue in eevee

Tags: geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine, transparency

Im using geometry nodes to render condensation droplets on the surface of a can in blender 4.0.
I have modelled a small droplet and shaded it with glass shader.
Im using EEVEE.

However, when I render it the droplets on the edges of the frame look white. Also in viewport as a matter of fact.
Im not aware of the cause and I'm pretty new to blender.[image: Render]

[image: Water Material Settings]

Comment: Hello ! As the name implies screen space refraction happens in screen space, so artifacts are common when you get near the edge of the screen. One solution is to render a frame a bit larger than intended and crop the borders in post production

Comment: Oh I see... Thank you so much!

Comment: Alternatively, I noticed that in the render settings, under screen space refractions, we can turn the edge fading to zero to remove this effect.

Comment: That would make more sense. It might introduce other artifacts though